# Karaf OSGI Bundles Closing on Startup

Tags: osgi-bundle, karaf, blueprint-osgi, opendaylight

I am having issues with karaf/osgi and when i try to start karaf some of my features loop through starting and closing. Here is a log example:

```
2017-09-05 15:46:03,344 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | L3vpnProvider                    | 224 - l3vpn-feature-impl - 0.1.0.SNAPSHOT | L3vpnProvider Session Initiated
2017-09-05 15:46:03,346 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | L3vpnDataChangeListenerSR        | 171 - org.temp.l3vpn-impl - 0.1.0.SNAPSHOT | Service Request Data Listener created
2017-09-05 15:46:03,349 | INFO  | ntAdminThread #7 | BlueprintBundleTracker           | 144 - org.opendaylight.controller.blueprint - 0.5.3.Boron-SR3 | Blueprint container for bundle org.temp.l3vpn-feature-impl_0.1.0.SNAPSHOT [224] was successfully created
2017-09-05 15:46:03,353 | INFO  | Thread-193       | L3vpnProvider                    | 224 -l3vpn-feature-impl - 0.1.0.SNAPSHOT | L3vpnProvider Closed
```

And it literally loops and does not stop. The only solution i've found is constant rebuilding until it starts without complications.

Here is the feature in the feature.xml file to show you how its setup.

```
<feature name='odl-l3vpn-feature-impl' version='${project.version}' description='OpenDaylight :: l3vpn :: Network Model :: Impl'>
    <feature version='${mdsal.version}'>odl-mdsal-broker</feature>
    <feature version='${project.version}'>odl-l3vpn-network-model</feature>
    <feature version='${project.version}'>odl-l3vpn</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:org.temp/l3vpn-nc-impl/{{VERSION}}</bundle>
    <lots of other bundles being wrapped>
</feature>
```

There is an additional feature but it has a very similiar structure so i will not put that up unless it is needed.

I am just a loss for what could be causing this to occur. Are there any ideas?

What i've already tried to do is make the odl-mdsal-broker have a prerequisite or dependency element set as true to make sure there wasn't problems starting the bundle too early but there was no luck with that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may be having the same issue. This was because of a startup error where both features in the blueprint xml had the same config file, so on startup they were getting confused which caused a loop of booting. After renaming one of the config files and updating that in the blueprint.xml this solved the issue.